# Is it OK to give unsolicited advice?

Tags: discussion, answers

A little while ago I saw a question on Stack Overflow, wherein the user posted some of his code, and asked why he was experiencing stack overflow exceptions. Several other people had already provided very helpful answers on how he could resolve the issue, and so I did not feel the need to repeat the same advice.

However, I did notice that this user can significantly improve his code by making it more readable and using more efficient data structures. I hesitate to give him refactoring-related feedback, since he did not post his code on Code Review, and did not explicitly invite advice that is not relevant to helping him handle stack overflow exceptions.

So my question is: Is it appropriate to give unsolicited advice when I notice something that could be greatly improved? In such scenarios, should I give my feedback as a comment, or as an answer?

Comment: Yes. No. Here's my unsolicited advice: this is the question for meta Stack Overflow, not meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Deer not sure about that, such advice can be given on other sites as well, e.g. cooking: "I see you are using [name of ingredient A], but you really better use [name of ingredient B] instead"

Comment: @ShadowWizard - your unsolicited advice convinced me to retract the CV. MSO has some nice Q&As on "premature optimization advice" etc., though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't think this question is off-topic here, but I do think that it would be *better* asked at meta.SO. Yes, the same question could be meaningfully asked for any site, but *the details of the answer may vary* depending on the topic and on local community norms.

Comment: For example, on Code Review, unsolicited advice would be perfectly on-topic.  That's one of the reasons why Code Review and Stack Overflow are different sites:  so they can have different rules.

Answer (score 8):

**If you're giving it as a comment underneath the question, then it is okay.**

However, if you are writing an answer for that sole purpose and if doesn't even answer the question, then it is not okay. In fact, you might and would be downvoted for that too, as your answer wouldn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you have to go a little further to really help the OP. Some questions are clearly a X/Y problem for example. You can answer Y, but if the problem is really X, you can go the step further and explain how to solve the actual issue.

This is okay as long as your answer is actually answering the question at hand. Giving advice on top of the answer is okay, and even very appreciated, since it makes the site better.

You should be careful though when posting an answer without really answering the question. This is not a discussion board where you can post random posts. If you do want to give some advice in that situation, a comment might be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Readability and lucidity in code is an important concept most people don’t think about and often take for granted. If someone can’t make heads or tails out of badly formatted code, then it only makes the job of someone debugging—or assisting in debugging—even harder. Remember even the most seemingly incomprehensible computer code should be human readable on some level… Unless we’re talking about assembler code or even raw bits/bytes/hex and that’s a whole other can of worms.

I often leave comments about readability and general coherent nature of posts, but primarily do so only in comments. Sometimes if I get to answer a question I will reformat code and state very clearly about how readability makes it easier for them as well as others who want to help them [such as this one](https://superuser.com/a/1035431/167207).

At the end of the day, coherent and readable code helps everyone; the original poster as well as those who want to help them debug code. So in the spirit of being helpful always figure out the best way to help someone make their code more readable if you find it unreadable or difficult to comprehend. Either leave a comment if you have no answer but believe the presented code formatting is problematic or post a full/new answer if you have one and be sure to mention formatting in your answer.